# Using Liquibase with Snowflake

Tags: database-design, liquibase, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, changelog

Did anyone try to use the [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) with Snowflake DW? Trying to create the catalog tables but it's failing while creating the CREATE TABLE STATEMENT. Not sure where the table script is located. I would edit the same. Please let me know if anyone has any idea, else would pull the project from Git and would update the same.

[image]

Comment: The error is indicating that you do not have an active database selected.  Try either setting a default database in the user role or passing the database into your connection string.

Answer (score 3):

Figured out finally -

We need to use the extensions for Snowflake -

https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/spaces/CONTRIB/pages/113372651/Snowflake+extension

Downloaded the jar from the link above and placed it in lib where we place the other DB drivers.

Followed additional steps mentioned in the following GitHub link -

https://github.com/bruce-szalwinski/liquibase-snowflake-sample

Finally, execute the command using the following syntax -

```
liquibase --databaseClass=liquibase.ext.snowflake.database.SnowflakeDatabase update
```

The rest of the properties were configured in the liquibase.properties.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, liquidbase expects you to enter a JDBC URL which specifies the database name.

https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html

So could you add "db" parameter (and even warehouse parameter) to your URL as it's shown in the following link?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#examples

Answer (score 0):

The generated SQL is quite odd in that it appears fully qualified but isn't.

It should read: `"ORCL_SDDM_POC"."CUSTOMER"."DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK"` instead of `"ORCL_SDDM_POC.CUSTOMER.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK"`.

Even if you specify the default database and schema as part of the connection parameters, the outcome will appear as an oddly named table within it.

Are you perhaps customizing the `databaseChangeLogTableName` or `databaseChangeLogLockTableName` configurations within your `liquibase.properties` file? I'd recommend removing those if you are, and simply supply `?db=ORCL_SDDM_POC&schema=CUSTOMER&warehouse=YOUR_WH_NAME` as part of the Snowflake JDBC URL.

Consider describing what customizations you've performed in the `examples/sql` directory of your Liquibase download that you are attempting to execute.